# Play framework / Akka Streams: Detecting when a WebSocket has closed

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-stream

When handling WebSockets with Akka Streams directly, I didn't find a proper way to know when the client disconnects (either normally or due to a crash or timeout). I'm using a basic example like the one from the official documentation:

```
import play.api.mvc._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._

def socket = WebSocket.accept[String, String] { request =>

  // Log events to the console
  val in = Sink.foreach[String](println)

  // Send a single 'Hello!' message and then leave the socket open
  val out = Source.single("Hello!").concat(Source.maybe)

  Flow.fromSinkAndSource(in, out)
}
```

I need to know when a client is no longer connected.

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Comment: To broadcast a message to others that he left, Jeffrey Chung's suggestion is what i was looking for.

Comment: @ArnoutEngelen — a WS app typically needs to clean up some internal state, when a connection closes. E.g. a dictionary of who is online, and should be sent this or that type of message.   + what @ faissalb wrote above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`watchTermination`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/watchTermination.html):

```
def socket = WebSocket.accept[String, String] { request =>
  val in = Sink.foreach[String](println)
  val out = Source.single("Hello!").concat(Source.maybe)

  Flow.fromSinkAndSource(in, out)
    .watchTermination() { (_, fut) =>
      fut onComplete {
        case Success(_) =>
          println("Client disconnected")
        case Failure(t) =>
          println(s"Disconnection failure: ${t.getMessage}")
      }
    }
}
```